# Firebase AT Command HTTP POST

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, arduino, http-post, at-command, gprs

I am trying to do a post with a GPRS module in Firebase Database. The AT commands to the modem are being sent by Arduino Uno.

```
GPRScommand("AT+CIPSEND", ">", "yy", 10000, 1);
delay(500);
GPRSboard.print("POST /.json?auth=");
GPRSboard.print(FIREBASE_AUTH);
GPRSboard.print(" HTTP/1.1");
GPRSboard.print("\r\n");
GPRSboard.print("Host: ");
GPRSboard.print("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-461a8.firebaseio.com");
GPRSboard.print("\r\n");
GPRSboard.print("Content-Type: ");
GPRSboard.print("application/json");
GPRSboard.print("\r\n");
GPRSboard.print("Content-Length: 16");
GPRSboard.print("\r\n");   
GPRSboard.print("Cache-Control: ");
GPRSboard.print("no-cache");
GPRSboard.print("\r\n");
GPRSboard.print("\r\n");
GPRSboard.print("{\"param1\":\"7\"}");
GPRScommand(end_c, "HTTP/1.1", "yy", 30000, 1);
```

It returns me:

```
+CIPRCV:384,HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

I have tried using Postman. When I write the data I want to publish in the "Body TAB" of postman it works. I write in JSON Format:

```
{
"param1":"7"
}
```

But I think I need the code in x-www-form-urlencoded or text format I really do not know.

If I see the "code" generated by Postman in the succesfull post I have this:

```
POST /.json?auth=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX HTTP/1.1
Host: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-461a8.firebaseio.com
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache Postman-Token: 2f95151e-52e1-28e7-9583-c0a8f50f77d7
{ "param1":"7" }
```

That's what I have tried to send to GPRS Module and I receive HTTP Error 400 bad request, how I have told at the beginning.

Somebody can help me?

Thank you very much

Comment: Why is there no `Content-Length: 16` header? Also the URL is different? (`.json` vs `/.json`, which is very weird page name by itself) Also you need a *double* `\r\n` after the headers before the content.

Comment: Hello Maximilian, I have done what you suggested (you were right) but I am still having the same answer from the server (bad request). I think It should be something related with https, if I try to connect to htttp... un port 80, the connection is refused (however with postman It works). With the GPRS módem I receive ok, yo the connection request when I try to https... in port 443

Comment: Then edit your question and add the current code to it with the output. At this point it would now be good if you sent the request to the URL `http://httpbin.org/post` -- the answer will contain your exact request in JSON format. You can then debug what the gprs module actually sends and can idenitfy a problem there. If it look like the request is identical to the request Postman does but still doesn't return anything, your implementation of sending GPRS commands may be wrong. Also I didn't understand what port you're connecting to now? Sending raw HTTP request on 443 won't work without TLS.

Comment: Thanks, I have edit the original post. I am trying to do a POST to https://... at port 443 (which I receive OK in the connection), but obviously if I don't work with TLS it won't work. When I do what I have written, I receive "HTTP 400 error. Bad Request" If I try to connect to http://... at port 80 the server refused the connection.I don't understand why it works with Postman http:// and https://. Anyway, I will try httpbin, but it seems I am going to need to develop and run a script in a server, may be in php, which receives my http post and manage the request to Firebase Server.

Comment: Firebase Google Group said clear they do not allow HTTP traffic instead of HTTPS in this post... https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/mDpX2tidi6M

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but an aside comment.  You could make your code smaller and more readable by using this notation, or similar.

[EDIT:] This has helped me parse your request and spot that the `Content-Length` is 16, while it should be 14.

```
GPRSboard.print(
    "POST /.json?auth=" + FIREBASE_AUTH + " HTTP/1.1\r\n"
    "Host: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-461a8.firebaseio.com\r\n"
    "Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
    "Content-Length: 16\r\n"
    "Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n"
    "\r\n"
    "{\"param1\":\"7\"}"      /* <- contents is only this line, 14 bytes */
);
```

Comment: Hello Michaël, thanks for your comment you were right the "Content-Lenght" was 14, no 16. But this change does not solve the problem it continues giving me the same HTTP 400 Bad Request error. I will try to implement this solution which is not the desirable one but it could work: http://www.devacron.com/arduino-firebase/

Answer (score 0):

I also am facing the same issue.

I managed to post via processing: I've replaced all values with generic text.

```
PostRequest post = new PostRequest("https://XXXXXX.firebaseio.com/message_list.json");
  post.addJson("{\"Key\":" + 100 + "}");
  post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  post.addHeader("Authorization", "key=XXXXXX");
  post.send();
  System.out.println("Reponse Content: " + post.getContent());
  System.out.println("Reponse Content-Length Header: " + post.getHeader("Content-Length"));
```

I've tried to create a POST request on my arduino via AT command:

```
char* request =  "POST / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: XXXXXX.firebaseio.com/.json?auth=XXXXXX\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nContent-Length: XX\r\n\r\n{\"Key\":\"value\"}\r\n";
```

also in the format:

```
char* request =  "POST / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: https://XXXXXX/message_list.json\r\nAuthorization: key=XXXXXX\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nContent-Length: 13\r\n\r\n{\"hello\":\"2\"}";
```

tried also with no content

```
char* request =  "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: https://airwatch-yuki.firebaseio.com/message_list.json\r\nAuthorization: key=AIzaSyAgYd0MIblEmo4elyxAYpAdgXhNTweVqhw\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\n\r\n";
```

Which posts

```
POST / HTTP/1.0
Host: https://XXXXXX.firebaseio.com/message_list.json
Authorization: key=XXXXXX
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 13

{"hello":"2"}
```

But get the following error:

```
+IPD,179:HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 54
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 23 Nov 2017 18:08:48 GMT

<html><title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title></html>CLOSED
```

I initially had this Bad request when I was creating the code in processing. But solved it when I used the .addjson function for the key, value. I'm not sure what the difference is with the char request.

Comment: Please edit your answer to say where the `val` variable comes from. That seems to be essential to your answer.

Comment: In place of val, I had an int, for example 100, just to test that this works (and it works for the processing sketch). 
I've dug deeper and it may be that the doing a POST request through the arduino as above doesn't create a json object format that is needed? I'm still in the process of understanding why this is the case. What is the difference with the processing sketch or other languages where we do a data=json.dumps(data),